# In Eclipse, I have a list or a map with many entries -- is there a way to search for a particular value?

Tags: java, eclipse

I mean simply, say I have a List maybe with a bunch of file names, I would find it very helpful to see if a given file is in that List or entry set for a map. Can this be done in the Eclipse debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Just set a debug mark(breakpoint) at the position where you expect it to be in the map/list, and check the map value by clicking on the map/list instance, this way you should see what values are in the instance at the given time

here is a [debug tutorial for eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) to use some of the more advanced debug options

the condtion to break on a contained in eclipse goes like

```
if(list.contains("hello")){
    return false;}
    return true;
```

like wise you can have a test that prints something but doesn't trigger a breakpoint by doing

```
if(list.contains("hello")){
    System.out.println("list contains: " + "hello");
    return false;}
else{
    System.out.println("list does not contain: " + "hello");
    return false;
}
```

note that printing and other similar things can acces the current state in the program at the time of the breakpoint.

Assuming a value is known and a list say

```
public String value = "hello";
public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.print("done");
```

and the break point apears at the 3rd line, then this conditional breakpoint can be defined

```
if(list.contains(value)){
    System.out.println("list contains: " + value);
    return false;}
else{
    System.out.println("list does not contain: " + value);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Say the list has 1000 entries and I want to see if one named "foo" is among them?

Comment: Look at the link i added, there is advanced options for breakpoints to only break if a specifc thing happens, more specifically look at the section 2.1

Comment: @Jeff the breakpoints condition should be something like "list.contains(someObject), then the breakpoint should only trigger if the entry is in the list, ofc this requires that you know what entry you are looking for, like wise you can make it if break if the entry is not available using !list.contains(someObject)

Comment: @Jeffwas this helpfull ? or should i be more specific ?

Comment: Still seeing if I can do what I want. This might be as close to what I need in Eclipse as I can get but it is not really what I am asking for as I understand it so far.

Comment: @Jeff i see, well how do you prefer to get the feed back if the object is in the list ?

Comment: @Jeff so i tested the precise code to break at the content of a list and it goes like i added in the answer

Comment: So, in other words, you would like to search for a particular value at runtime, rather than a preset value, is that correct?

Comment: searching for a particular value is possible like this, because at the time of the breakpoint, all values can be acced in the scope, meaning that if a list is there, and the value to search for is there, the condition can be "if(list.contains(value))" similar to the examples above

Comment: @Jeff further elaborated the use of the debugger in eclipse to define functions for testing if a specific value is present at the time of the break point

Comment: @Mikenno, I think that will work but the need to set a breakpoint is sort of indirect.